# twilio programmable voice sdk server configuration not dialing a call

Tags: twilio

In the server configuration i write

```
   @app.route('/outgoing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def outgoing():
  resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
  #resp.say("Congratulations! You have made your first oubound call! Good bye.")
  resp.dial('mynumber')
  return str(resp)

@app.route('/placeCall', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def placeCall():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
  api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
  client = Client(api_key, api_key_secret, account_sid)
  CALLER_ID = request.values.get('From')
  IDENTITY = request.values.get('To')
  call = client.calls.create(url=request.url_root+'outgoing',to= IDENTITY, from_= CALLER_ID)
  return str(call.sid)
```

and on swift side i have implemented

```
 @IBAction func placeCall(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let accessToken = fetchAccessToken() else {
            return
        }

        outgoingCall = VoiceClient.sharedInstance().call(accessToken, params: ["To":"mynumber","From":"16467831648"], delegate: self)

        if (outgoingCall == nil) {
            NSLog("Failed to start outgoing call")
            return
        }

        toggleUIState(isEnabled: false)
        startSpin()
    }
```

the person who is calling getting a voice message "an application error has occured" when this end at my end  send a voice message to a person who is reciving  "congratulation you have made your first call press any number to continue" and call ends can anyone help how to git rid of voice message

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Could you be a little clearer. What are you trying to achieve and what documentation are you following?

Comment: when i'm configuring this on server side the person to whom i have to call get an voice message saying "Congratulations! You have received your first inbound call! Good bye."  because of this link wriitten in server configuration that say  so  I'am not able to talk to that person can you help me what's wrong in this i have [use this link to configure](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You've made the first call with your iOS app, which is awesome! Now you can start to customise it.

You'll now need to learn about [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), which is the XML that we use to control Twilio calls. As you've already seen, you're using a Python server to return the TwiML, which is built up and [returned in this code](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python/blob/master/server.py#L36-L40). This uses [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) to speak the message to you.

If you want to dial on to another number, then you'll want to take a look at [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), which can be used to forward calls or set up conferences. To update your server to use dial instead, you could change the action to this:

```
@app.route('/outgoing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def outgoing():
  resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
  resp.dial("NUMBER_TO_DIAL")
  return str(resp)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: i have implemented this when i'am dialing i'm getting a voice message "an error has occured" and on the another to whom I'm calling getting a voice message "congratulation  you have successfully made your first call press any key to continue" but not able to talk.please help to get rid of this

Comment: Are you calling app to app?

Comment: i'am calling from app to phone

Comment: Can you edit your question and share a bit more of your code that you're using? I'm not sure how you are getting two calls at the moment.

Comment: Does your TwiML app set the voice URL as `/place_call`?

Comment: yes i have implmented serverpath/placeCall in twiml app

Comment: So, rather than generating a new call in /place_call, you should respond with the Dial TwiML that I put in my original answer.

Comment: when doing this then i'm getting voice message in my end "An application error has occured" and not getting voice message at reciver end .I think thier is a problem in

resp.dial("number") it's not working

Comment: Are you putting the actual number you are trying to call in? Also, can you check the Twilio debugger in the Twilio console and let me know the error message.